# vectorize a comparison operation between of rows of a dataframe with multiindex columns

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with multindex columns and time series data.  I want to create a new set of columns where the value of a cell in that column is a boolean dependent on whether some other column of that row is identical value to the previous row. In other words, a boolean 'did the value of interest change?' for each set of columns.  In this example below,  'dave' weight change is true  for 11-27 because it change to 80 from 83 the previous week. The other two names are false, because their weights didn't change.

[image]

I have a really kludgy row-by-row iterative solution but I'd prefer to replace it with a vectorized solution I could apply to the entire dataframe. But I don't see how to do it.

```
import random
idx = pd.IndexSlice
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["mike", "matt", "dave"], ['weight', 'drug', 'weight_change']])
index = pd.date_range(start="2022-10-30",  end="2022-12-3" ,freq="w", )


df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=cols)

for name in ['mike', 'matt', 'dave']:
    df.loc[:, idx[name,'drug']] = random.sample(['a','b','a','a','a','c','a','c'], k=5)
    df.loc[:,idx[name, 'weight']] = random.sample([80,80,80,80,82,83,80, 80, 80], k=5)
    
#gross iterative solution
one_row = df.iloc[-2].loc[:,'weight'] != df.iloc[-1].loc[:,'weight'] 

pd.MultiIndex.from_product([one_row.index, ['weight_change',]])
one_row.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([one_row.index, ['weight_change',]])
one_row

df.loc['2022-11-27',idx[:,'weight_change']] = one_row
```

=============

followup, I had a similar operation but the data i was comparing was non-numeric, therefore `diff()` won't work.    So instead I passed `ne()` a `shifted` version of the dataframe slice and it worked.  Example below

```
import random
idx = pd.IndexSlice
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["mike", "matt", "dave"], [ 'drug', 'mood', 'weight', 'mood_change', 'weight_change']])
index = pd.date_range(start="2022-10-30",  end="2022-12-3" ,freq="w", )


df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=cols)

for name in ['mike', 'matt', 'dave']:
    df.loc[:, idx[name,'drug']] = random.sample(['a','b','a','a','a','c','a','c'], k=5)
    df.loc[:,idx[name, 'mood']] = random.sample(['alert', 'alert', 'dull', 'dull', 'alert', 'alert'], k=5)
    df.loc[:,idx[name, 'weight']] = random.sample([80,80,80,80,82,83,80, 80, 80], k=5)

d = {'weight':'weight_change', 'mood':'mood_change'}
df.loc[df.index[1]:,idx[:, 'weight_change']] = df.loc[df.index[1]:,idx[:, 'weight']].diff().ne(0).rename(columns = d)

#for comparing non-numeric
df.loc[df.index[1]:,idx[:, 'mood_change']] = df.loc[df.index[1]:,idx[:, 'mood']].ne(df.loc[df.index[1]:,idx[:, 'mood']].shift()).rename(columns = d)
df
```

Comment: First row should be `True` or `False`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for get levels `weight` with [`DataFrame.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) and compare for not equal `0`, last set to levels `weight_change`, so for align columns use `rename`:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
d = {'weight':'weight_change'}
df.loc[:, idx[:,'weight_change']]=df.loc[:,idx[:, 'weight']].diff().ne(0).rename(columns=d)
print (df)
             mike                      matt                      dave       \
           weight drug weight_change weight drug weight_change weight drug   
2022-10-30     80    a          True     80    a          True     80    c   
2022-11-06     83    a          True     80    a         False     82    c   
2022-11-13     80    b          True     80    b         False     80    a   
2022-11-20     80    a         False     80    a         False     80    a   
2022-11-27     80    a         False     80    c         False     80    a   

                          
           weight_change  
2022-10-30          True  
2022-11-06          True  
2022-11-13          True  
2022-11-20         False  
2022-11-27         False
```

If need first row omit (get original `NaN`s):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice

d = {'weight':'weight_change'}

df1 = df.loc[:, idx[:, 'weight']].diff().rename(columns=d)
df.loc[df.index[1]:, idx[:, 'weight_change']] = df1.ne(0)
print (df)
             mike                      matt                      dave       \
           weight drug weight_change weight drug weight_change weight drug   
2022-10-30     82    c           NaN     82    c           NaN     83    a   
2022-11-06     80    c          True     80    c          True     80    c   
2022-11-13     80    a         False     80    b         False     82    a   
2022-11-20     80    a         False     83    a          True     80    c   
2022-11-27     80    a         False     80    a          True     80    a   

                          
           weight_change  
2022-10-30           NaN  
2022-11-06          True  
2022-11-13          True  
2022-11-20          True  
2022-11-27         False
```

Another idea for manual set `NaN`s for first row and compare non numeric values:

```
#for comparing non-numeric
df1 = df.loc[df.index[1]:,idx[:, 'mood']]
df1 = df1.ne(df1.shift()).rename(columns = d)
df1.iloc[0] = np.nan
df.loc[:,idx[:, 'mood_change']] = df1
print (df)
           mike                                         matt                \
           drug   mood weight mood_change weight_change drug   mood weight   
2022-10-30    a   dull     80         NaN           NaN    a   dull     80   
2022-11-06    a  alert     80         NaN          True    a   dull     80   
2022-11-13    a  alert     80         0.0         False    b  alert     80   
2022-11-20    a  alert     80         0.0         False    a  alert     80   
2022-11-27    c   dull     80         1.0         False    c  alert     82   

                                     dave                            \
           mood_change weight_change drug   mood weight mood_change   
2022-10-30         NaN           NaN    a  alert     80         NaN   
2022-11-06         NaN          True    b  alert     80         NaN   
2022-11-13         1.0         False    a   dull     80         1.0   
2022-11-20         0.0         False    c   dull     83         0.0   
2022-11-27         0.0          True    a  alert     80         1.0   

                          
           weight_change  
2022-10-30           NaN  
2022-11-06          True  
2022-11-13         False  
2022-11-20          True  
2022-11-27          True
```

Comment: I have edited my original question to show how I did the comparison when the underlying data is non-numeric (therefore `diff()` won't work.  Wondered if `ne(shift())` is how you would have approached it?

Comment: @user3556757 - I think it is correct approach.

Comment: @user3556757 - I create very similar solution and added to answer.